# Cannot get the file from recieved action_send from other apps

Tags: android

My app is supposed to be able to open any file from other applications

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

In the activity I try to get the file out of the intent

```
   Intent i = getIntent();
    String action = i.getAction();
    if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)){
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        Uri uri = (Uri)bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

Now, if the file is on my disk already and I share/open it with my app, it works fine. But if I try to export it from Dropbox or open it from some other app, later on in the code where I use my file, I get this error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /filecache/faf4b9ba-43c9-4292-807b-c18aae702b5a (No such file or directory)
```

Is it a problem with the filters (not being specific enough) or am I getting the file out of the intent in a wrong way?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Uri` is not a `File`. In fact, in most cases, the Uri you receive will be a `content://` Uri (particularly on Android 7.0+ devices where [you cannot share file:// Uris across apps](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files)) and you will *not* have direct access to the underlying file.

You should instead use [`getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) to get an `InputStream` to the contents of the `Uri` you receive.